# Update SQL Server database using a list

Tags: c#, t-sql, dao

I'm trying to update a SQL Server database and have a list of strings which are seat numbers

```
string strQuery = ("Update tblTransactionItems set selected = 'T' Where SeatNumber = @SeatNumber");

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, con)) {
    con.Open();

    foreach (var item in list) {
       string test = item.ToString();
       test = test.Replace('"', ' ').Trim();

       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SeatNumber", test);
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

It keeps saying that the variable `@SeatNumber` has been declared and only the first item in the list is updated. Any ways on how to approach this?

Update :

I just placed the foreach loop outside the using and it works.

Comment: because you add @seatnumber each itteration of your foreach loop building the string..

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to make a inlist but using a equality operator saying `Where SeatNumber = @SeatNumber"` where as you should using a `IN` operator like

```
Where SeatNumber IN (@SeatNumber)
```

Again this is not the right way, rather you should populate those inlist values to a `DataTable` and pass that as `DbType.Structured` instead

Answer (score 2):

Its because you have already added `CommandParameter` to `SqlCommand` and you are again adding it in loop

```
string strQuery = ("Update tblTransactionItems set selected = 'T' Where SeatNumber = @SeatNumber");
con.Open();
foreach (var item in list) {
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, con)) {
    string test = item.ToString();
    test = test.Replace('"', ' ').Trim();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SeatNumber", test);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initiate SqlCommand parameter every time. In your code you are using the SQLCommand to execute the query first time only and it updates your table with first item in the list. During the next iteration since the sqlcommand still holds the last value (query to update previous item from the list), it throws an error. The right way to do this is as follows:

```
try{
    string strQuery = ("Update tblTransactionItems set selected = 'T' Where SeatNumber = @SeatNumber");
    con.Open();
    foreach (var item in list) {
      using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, con)) {
    string test = item.ToString();
    test = test.Replace('"', ' ').Trim();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SeatNumber", test);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

      }
    }
}
finally{ con.Close() }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add one more clear parameter line to make it run.

```
string strQuery = ("Update tblTransactionItems set selected = 'T' Where SeatNumber = @SeatNumber");

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, con)) {
    con.Open();
    foreach (var item in list) {
        string test = item.ToString();
        test = test.Replace('"', ' ').Trim();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SeatNumber", test);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just placed the foreach loop outside the using and it works.